# Selenium/Java forgetting Facebook credentials

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, cookies, local-storage

So I'm writing some Selenium tests in Java with WebDriver to test a Facebook integration.
I have a couple of tests in which I'd like to log in to Facebook in the beginning.
So since I'd like a fresh clean browser so before every test I run the following:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.localStorage.clear();");
}
```

But somehow, after the first test my browser still remembers me as logged into Facebook.

How do I properly reset this without tearing the whole browser down?

Thanks!

Comment: Facebook has a logout link, maybe just use that URL? It looks like it's not the cookies where the information that you are logged in is stored (makes me wonder where that is stored, i would suspect it's not just in the URL parameters, that would be really unsecure)

Comment: Yeah, I considered that as well, it just seems less "nice", and I'm thinking someone must have solved this before somehow. :)

Comment: you cant ,since the session is open on the server side , so you have to close down the browser to shutdwon the session or logout

Comment: You are aware that cookies are different from local storage?

Comment: @StackOver that's normal, but the server needs a way to identify you. That is what cookies do (it would be a really bad idea to use the IP). Deleting the cookie (or whatever is used to track the session) basically means a one-sided termination of the session because you lose your "ticket", so to say, and you need to re-authenticate to get a new one (= new session)